# Using a for loop in pandas

Tags: excel, pandas

I have 2 different tabular files, in excel formats. I want to know if an id number from one of the columns in the first excel file (from the "ID" column) exists in the proteome file in a specific column (take "IHD" for example) and if so, to display the value associated with it. Is there a way to do this, specifically in pandas and possible using a for loop?

[image: I want to use the last coluumn "ID" to basically cross-reference the other file]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the excel files with [**`read_excel()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), you should [**`merge()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the dataframes on `ID` and `protein`. This is the recommended approach with pandas rather than looping.

```py
import pandas as pd

clusters = pd.read_excel('clusters.xlsx')
proteins = pd.read_excel('proteins.xlsx')

clusters.merge(proteins, left_on='ID', right_on='protein')
```

Comment: @MarissaP hard to say without being able to see the data. what is the output of `proteins.columns`?